# Effecient modules which will give me users location and country information

Tags: 7

I am using drupal 7. I searched and found lot many modules to give users location and country information. So just wanted to know which is the efficient module which i should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Smart IP](http://drupal.org/project/smart_ip).

> Smart IP identify visitor's geographical location (longitude/latitude), country, region, city and postal code based on the IP address of the user. These information will be stored at session variable (`$_SESSION`) with array key 'smart_ip' and Drupal `$user->data` object with array key 'geoip_location' of the user but optionally it can be disabled (by role) at Smart IP admin page.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [IP-based Determination of a Visitor's Country](http://drupal.org/project/ip2country) module.